# Counting the 1s in each row of the incidence matrix of a 2-design

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

Consider the $2 - (4t-1, 2t, t)$ design where $t$ is an odd number and $A$ is the incidence matrix. I suspect that the number of elements with value $1$ in each row of $A$ is equal to $2t$ but I can't prove it. Any comments and ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, that is a typo. One more thing A is a 4t-1 x 4t-1 matrix, this is clear from another context which I didn't mention. A theorem I'm trying to understand states that (I , J - A) is 4t-1 x 8t-2 matrix where I is the identity matrix and J is matrix composed of 1s only.

Comment: One of the first results you should have seen is that for any $2$-$(v,k,\lambda)$ design, the *replication number* $r$ (defined to be the number of blocks incident with a point, i.e., the number of $1$'s in each row of the incidence matrix) is equal to $\lambda(v-1)/(k-1)$. For example, see Chapter 19 of Van Lint and Wilson's book "A Course in Combinatorics."

Comment: The thing is that the very same theorem states that each row of the matrix (I, J - A) contains 2t 1s. Since I has only one 1 per row, J has 4t-1 1s per row, A has to have exactly 2t 1s per each row obviously but I can't prove that.

Comment: @Casteels - thanks! I will take a look.

Comment: @Casteels - Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!